# Quoting the Good News Translation (GNT) of the Bible in Books (Commercial Usage) - Allowed or Infringes Copyright?

Tags: copyright

Can the Good News Translation (GNT) of the Bible (copyrighted by American Bible Society) be quoted for commercial usage as part of a book's (ebook, paperback & audiobook versions) or if that would infringe upon their copyright?

https://www.bibles.com/services/licensing-information/ (last bullet below) suggests it can't be used for any commercial usage

> Summary of Fair Use Policy (All conditions must apply):
>
> · No more than 500 verses in total may be reproduced without
>   permission
>
> · Scripture/Verses may not make up more than 25% of the new work
>
> · Verses quoted do not amount to 50% of a complete book of the Bible
>
> · All Scripture must be properly cited with the appropriate copyright
>   notice (see below)
>
> · The book or product must be available for non-commercial use.

https://www.americanbible.org/about/legal/copyrights - bullet #1 seems to suggest it can be used if used within the limit specified there & bullet 2 (which includes verbiage for commercial usage) only applies if it exceeds the bullet 1's limits:

> Policy for use of the Good News Translation (GNT)
>
> General Statement: The GNT text may be quoted in any form (written,
>   visual, electronic or audio) up to and inclusive of five hundred (500)
>   verses without written permission, providing the verses quoted do not
>   amount to 50% of a complete book of the Bible nor do the verses
>   account for twenty-five percent (25%) or more of the total text of the
>   work in which they are quoted. This permission is contingent upon an
>   appropriate copyright acknowledgment – (see below).
>
> Use of the GNT beyond above limits requires written permission.
>
> Commercial Use: Commercial use means use in any product offered for
>   sale, lease, rental or barter on any level. Rights and permissions
>   requests for the GNT in media intended for commercial use should be
>   addressed to The American Bible Society, 101 North Independence Mall
>   East FL8 Philadelphia PA 19106-2112, USA . Request shall contain the
>   following information:
>
> (1) exact portions to be quoted,
>
> (2) the medium in which those portions will be quoted,
>
> (3) estimated percentage of the total text of the work made up of the
>   GNT text,
>
> (4) any additional material to be included in the work, such as
>   additional text, illustrations, photos, etc.,
>
> (5) the purpose, number of copies or reproductions, and distribution
>   of the use in which the GNT is quoted, and
>
> (6) the sale or lease price of the work, or other income to be
>   received.
>
> For commercial use outside of North America, please send your requests
>   as detailed above to the American Bible Society. If the GNT is used as
>   the lyrics for a song, you must obtain permission prior to production
>   of the same.

Comment: Why not ask them? And / or get written permission.

Comment: Bible is public domain (although the specific translation may need to be looked at) and has been probably longer than the mainstream adaptation of Christianity.  Certainly there are translations that have been in public domain for some time as well (Like the King James Bible)